# Pandas Pivot Table Formatting

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, pivot-table

Trying to do Stock Options pivot table by Ticker Symbol.
Current dataframe output:

[image]

Goal:

[image]

Got this far, but I am missing 1.A summed row by ticker symbol and 2. Sorting by value:

```
options_df_byTicker = pd.pivot_table(options_df,index=['Ticker','contractSymbol'],values=['dollarsTradedTodayApprox'],aggfunc=np.sum)
```

[image]

Comment: Hi Pavel, subtotal for pivot has been solved here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41383302/pivot-table-subtotals-in-pandas

Comment: pandas pivot table sort by values: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41119623/pandas-pivot-table-sort-values-by-columns